# How to make the Ubuntu login screen "controls" bigger?

Tags: login-screen, 16.10

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 on a laptop carrying out a HDPI screen and I managed to have a decent experience until now (Large Text enabled in the universal access, and the Scale for menu and title bars set 1.25 in the Display panel).

So my question is not so much about how to change the login screen resolution but how to make it look the same as when I just say lock my session (since then the login screen seems using the display settings of my session).